# With Pandas, can you only extract the date from a to_period function that shows a range of dates (2020-02-10/2020-02-16)?

Tags: python, pandas, date

here are how the dates format when I call `to_period`

Code given below:

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.to_period(freq='W'))

date
2020-02-10/2020-02-16
2020-02-17/2020-02-23
2020-02-24/2020-03-01
2020-03-02/2020-03-08
```

However, I only want to show the first date, so it would look like this:

```
date
2020-02-10
2020-02-17
2020-02-24
2020-03-02
```

I tried using `strftime` to take only the year, month, and date. However, this selects the second day instead of the first from the same row.

I'm grouping by week

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.to_period(freq='W'))['interviews'].sum().reset_index().sort_values('date')
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does the data look like before grouping?

Comment: Hi! Added a change

Comment: Can you paste the input dataframe instead of adding the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `.start_time`.
I'm not sure about your data, so I can use your groupby function, but something like this:

```
df.date.dt.to_period(freq='W').apply(lambda x: x.start_time)
```

or

```
df['week'] = df.date.dt.to_period(freq='W')
df.week.dt.start_time
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Can I ask, as a new programmer, what's the best way to find functions among so many?

Comment: Practice, Stack Overflow, and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
df['date'].str.split('/')
```